# javascript replace text at second occurence of "/"

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have this string

```
"/mp3/mysong.mp3"
```

I need to do make this string look like this with javascript.

```
"/mp3/myusername/mysong.mp3"
```

My guess would be to find second occurrence of "/", then append "myusername/" there or prepend "/myusername" but I'm not sure how to do this in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
var str = "/mp3/mysong.mp3";
var res = str.replace(/(.*?\/){2}/g, "$1myusername/");
console.log(res);
```

this will insert the text myusername after the 2nd `/` .

Answer (score 2):

Just capture the characters  upto the second `/` symbol and store it into a group. Then replace the matched characters with the characters inside group 1 plus the string `/myusername`

Regex:

```
^(\/[^\/]*)
```

Replacement string:

```
$1/myusername
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kU4lY1/3)

```
> var r = "/mp3/mysong.mp3"
undefined
> r.replace(/^(\/[^\/]*)/, "$1/myusername")
'/mp3/myusername/mysong.mp3'
```

OR

Use a lookahead.

```
> r.replace(/(?=\/[^/]*$)/, "/myusername")
'/mp3/myusername/mysong.mp3'
```

This `(?=\/[^/]*$)` matches a boundary which was just before to the last `/` symbol. Replacing the matched boundary with `/myusername` will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

This works -

```
>  "/mp3/mysong.mp3".replace(/(.*?\/)(\w+\.\w+)/, "$1myusername\/$2")
"/mp3/myusername/mysong.mp3"
```

Demo and explanation of the regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/hR8eA4/2)